# Linear mode is not working in mat-horizontal-stepper with separate components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular5

I, am trying to separate the component of each step in mat-horizontal-stepper as shown in the below html page.

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="selectAdvType">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>
      <div class="text-center">
        <mat-icon>queue_play_next</mat-icon><br /><span>Select Adv Type</span>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <app-advertisement-type></app-advertisement-type>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="selectCarAdvType">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>
      <div class="text-center">
        <mat-icon>directions_car</mat-icon><br /><span>Select Car</span>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <app-select-car-adv></app-select-car-adv>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>
      <div class="text-center">
        <mat-icon>description</mat-icon><br /><span>Select Features</span>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

**app-advertisement-type component**

```
<form [formGroup]="selectAdvType">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Last name, First name" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**app-select-car-adv component**

```
<form [formGroup]="selectCarAdvType">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Last name, First name" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
          <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
  </form>
```

**Validation on the component class**

```
export class AdvertisementTypeComponent implements OnInit {
  selectAdvType: FormGroup;
  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectAdvType = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

}
```

Since the linear functionality is not working. I, am able to navigate to the other component. How can I solve this.

Comment: Any Update on this ?

Comment: Can anyone give the answer how we can achieve the above

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You could access your child's components using **@ViewChild** and access the **child's form** from your parent's html, for example:

**parent.component.html**

```
 ...
 <mat-step [stepControl]="myChild.form">
       <my-child #myChild></my-child>
 </mat-step>
 ...
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
...
@ViewChild('myChild', { static: false }) myChild: MyChildComponent;
...
```

**my-child.component.ts**

```
...
public form: FormGroup;
...
```

**my-child.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   ...
</form>
```

**NOTE:** You don't need to use '{ static: false }' syntax if you are using Angular version below 8.

Comment: this is working for step2 and step3 but not working for step1

Comment: this works. But I get expression has been changed after it was checked error. I tried moving form initialization to the constructor too.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if you solve the problem or not. Set the firstCtrl as empty string will make the form valid all the time. Set `null` work for me.

```
export class AdvertisementTypeComponent implements OnInit {
  selectAdvType: FormGroup;
  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectAdvType = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstCtrl: [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }
}
```